# When unit testing with Chai, what does "TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined" mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I keep getting this error message when unit testing using chai and none of the tests passes even though they should. What does it mean in this context?
Thanks.

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var server = require('../server.js');

var should = chai.should();
var app = server.app;
var storage = server.storage;

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Shopping List', function() {
  it('should list items on GET', function(done) {
chai.request(app)
  .get('/items')
  .end(function(err, res) {
    res.should.have.status(200);
    res.should.be.json; // jshint ignore:line
    res.body.should.be.a('array');
    res.body.should.have.length(3);
    res.body[0].should.be.a('object');
    res.body[0].should.have.property('id');
    res.body[0].should.have.property('name');
    res.body[0].id.should.be.a('number');
    res.body[0].name.should.be.a('string');
    res.body[0].name.should.equal('Broad beans');
    res.body[1].name.should.equal('Tomatoes');
    res.body[2].name.should.equal('Peppers');
    done();
  });
   });
```

Full error message:

```
1) Shopping List should list items on GET:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined
      at serverAddress (/home/ubuntu/workspace/thinkful-node-course/unit2/node_modules/chai-http/lib/request.js:252:17)
      at new Test (/home/ubuntu/workspace/thinkful-node-course/unit2/node_modules/chai-http/lib/request.js:244:53)
      at Object.obj.(anonymous function) [as get] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/thinkful-node-course/unit2/node_modules/chai-http/lib/request.js:216:14)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test-server.js:14:8)
```

Comment: It seems that `app` is not a valid Node app (doesn't have an `address` property).

Comment: could you post the file `server.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problems: first had to make sure that the file I was testing, server.js was exported properly to the test.js file.

Also I forgot to put the test.js file inside a separate test folder. I wish the error message were not so ambiguous. Sent me on a wild goose chase as I struggled to fix the code itself.

Comment: Can you show me your code solution(serve.js and test.js)?, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using app try using:

```
chai.request('http://localhost:1234')
  .get('/items')
```

Comment: My issue solved using this method. But still, I don't know why exactly

Comment: This can work but it doesn't really solve the fundamental problem which is that the server hasn't exported a valid `app` object to the testing suite. The best way to debug is `console.log(require("./path-to-your-server"))` to see if it's potentially undefined or otherwise not a valid Express `app` object before passing it to `chai.request(app)`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the most probably with the variable `app` that is actually undefined, because this error is thrown in such situation, you need to check that you are correctly importing your server.js file and that it contains property app with instance of your server application.

Answer (score 0):

let's see how things work underhood

you have some base server request like below

=> server.js

```
let server = app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('node server running')
});
```

now your spec files remain on something like this => test/test.js

```
let request = require('request');
let chai = require('chai');
let assert = require('chai').assert;
let expect = require('chai').expect;
let server = require('../server');
// don't .js extension, common js handles it perfectly
let should = chai.should();

let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
chai.use(chaiHttp);
describe("/GET  all books",() => {
it('should return status 200 ', (done) => {
// dont forget done params 
//or else it will always give u test pass even if it is wrong  
//assertion
chai.request(server)
.get('/books/something/?q=something&num=23') // chai makes it easy..
.end((err, res) => {
  should.not.exist(err);
  should.exist(res); // note that u should check for res existance
  res.should.have.status(200);
  done();
  });
 });
});
```

So instead of `chai .request(app)`, it should be `chai.request(server)` to run the server from app.js or from a file in which test cases have to be written, the above code is for brief understanding sample code.

Comment: instead of chai .request(app), it should be chai.request(server)  to run the server from app.js or from a file in which test cases have to be written, the above code is for brief understanding sample code :)